# Increase size of apk file after added Paypal SDK

Tags: android, paypal-mobile-sdk, paypal-android-sdk

After added paypal sdk my apk size increses about 13 mb from its actual apk size. Used PayPal sdk for futur payment in andoird and gradle link added

```
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1')
```

how to reduce size for apk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't using io.card remove it from project like:

```
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.3') {
    exclude group: 'io.card'
}
```

Comment: but using this it remove paypal card functionality from your app